# Analyst Capability (ACAP) calculation in COCOMO

Tags: performance

I see the following information in the COCOMO documentation:

> Analysts are personnel that work on requirements, high level design
>   and detailed design. The major attributes that should be considered in
>   this rating are Analysis and Design ability, efficiency and
>   thoroughness, and the ability to communicate and cooperate. The rating
>   should not consider the level of experience of the analyst; that is
>   rated with AEXP. Analysts that fall in the 15th percentile are rated
>   very low and those that fall in the 95th percentile are rated as very
>   high
>
> - 15th percentile - Very Low
> - 35th percentile - Low
> - 55th percentile - Normal
> - 75th percentile High
> - 90th percentile - Very High

I don't know, how to calculate percentiles. Maybe there is some example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is very subjective, and changes from company to company. To measure "analysis and design ability, efficiency and thoroughness, and the ability to communicate and cooperate" takes a combination of *self and peer reviews*, *performance evaluations* and *expert judgement*. You can also use a kind of development ladder to assess where in the percentile scale someone should be. Look at [this one](http://www.construx.com/professionaldevelopment) for an example.